# HP GGW Server commands

Tags: printing, server, command, telnet, network-printers

I am trying to find any information on commands for JetDirect/HP GGW Server. The only mention I've been able to find in the past 4 days of searching was at [Python socket communication with HP print server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223291/python-socket-communication-with-hp-print-server). I'm currently working with HP GGW v1.0, but the JetDirect GGW v2 commands in that post seem to work as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the really late reply, I hope this is useful anyways. Keep in mind, I'm not 100% sure how all these commands work but this is just from experimenting.

`*Tested on a HP OfficeJet 6600 printer
*Connected to port 9220 via NetCat or Telnet 
*Commands appear to be case insensitive
*Maximum command length appears to be 4`

Commands:

**data**:
  Appears to work together with the command open

**devi**:
  Shows device info

**mpct**:
  No idea what it does, it takes numbers as input

**noop**:
  Assembly language do nothing command?

**open**:
  Accepts 4, 9, or 43

**quit**:
  Closes connection

**serv**:
  Appears to be related with the skid command. See skid for more info

`220 HP GGW server (version 1.0) ready
 serv PRINT
 250 2 PRINT`

**time**:
  Takes # of seconds as argument and will close the connection after # seconds

**skid**:
  Accepts 1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,14,15,17,39,43,40,96,97,98, or 99 as an argument. Depending on the number, it will print a message, for example:

`220 HP GGW server (version 1.0) ready
 skid 2
 250 2 PRINT`

This is all I figured out so far through different methods of testing I've done over the last couple days. If you have any more questions about certain commands function, I could give you a more in-depth explanation of what I know so far.

## **EDIT:**

After a lot more searching, I found the patent for the HP GGW protocol. This might help us better understand it

https://patents.google.com/patent/US6581098

Comment: No worries, I forgot about this post. I was pen testing my printer for fun. I'll have to start up again after reading your findings. Thank you.